# Error in #include <sal/main.h> when including in a c++ header

Tags: c++, libreoffice-calc

I'm working on a project to read/write to LibreOffice calc  sheets in a c++ application. The code I'm writing include the line  `#include <sal/main.h>`
In order to get the component context and so on to read/write to the .ods files.

I'm using Fedora Linux 34 with gnome 40 Wayland and code::blocks 20.03. In the project I used the paths /usr/lib64/libreoffice/sdk/include and /usr/lib64/libreoffice/sdk/lib for the headers and libraries respectively. When I try to compile, the project which has nothing more than the include lines, the compiler throws an error saying that there is an error in the types.h header in the line where #if defined(_MSC_VER) evaluates to false.

How to overcome this if I'm using Linux? I installed the SDK in a Linux distro so why the SDK gives this error checking the platform?

Thanks you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [answer to your other post](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/312428/error-in-include-salmainh-when-including-in-a-c-header/?answer=312448#post-id-312448):

```
g++ -I${OO_SDK_HOME}/include -DLINUX yoursource.cxx
```